# Отследить длинное нажатие на кнопки громкости

Tags: android

Вопрос. Как отследить длинное нажатие на кнопки громкости.
Делаю так

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    //if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP) 
    //{
        event.startTracking();

    //}
    return true;
    }
@Override
```

public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    // Обработайте отпускание клавиши, верните true, если обработка выполнена
  return true;
}

```
public boolean onKeyLongPress(int keyCode,KeyEvent event){
    if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN){
        //Do your stuff here
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Вниз", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT); toast.show();

        return true;
    }
    if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP){
        //Do your stuff here
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Вверх", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT); toast.show();

        return true;
    }
    return onKeyLongPress(keyCode,event);
}
```

Работает, только не работает системное изменение громкости

Comment: Тут посмотрите: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26340551/3212712

Answer (score 3):

Воспользуйтесь слушателем onKeyLongPress и проверьте код клавиши громкости.

```
 public boolean onKeyLongPress(int keyCode,KeyEvent event){
        if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN){
            //Do your stuff here
            return true;
        }
        return onKeyLongPress(keyCode,event);
    }
```

Comment: Если реализовать еще onKeyDown и onKeyUp, тогда ваш onKeyLongPress срабатывает на простое нажатие. Сам по себе ваш метод не хочет работать